# How to draw shapes at non-integer locations in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I get <kbd>TypeError: integer argument expected, got float</kbd> when I use point with float (non-integer) coordinates as the origin of cv2.putText or center of cv2.circle. It seems a shame that these shapes support anti-aliasing with cv2.LINE_AA but not allow floating-point positions.

Without scaling the image up, drawing them at the correct scale and then scaling back down, is there any way to draw these shapes at non-integer positions?

An example use case is to draw a ground-truth point and overlay it with the measured position. By rounding it to integers, as the error increases, there appears to be no error until a given threshold when a large error suddenly appears.

Comment: @rayryeng: The other question is too general. Mine is specifically about drawing in OpenCV. The answer in the other question is also not suitable for my needs as it about rasterisation and drawing lines in general.

Comment: @tdelaney: As above. I had to make a second comment as Stack Overflow allows only one @ per comment.